# how does actually spring integrates with struts 2

Tags: spring, struts, integration

I am new to Struts and searched online for tutorial and examples that shows integration 
of spring with struts 2.

Some examples talk about using struts spring plugin in struts-config.xml and some dont even have struts-config.xml file.

This is making me confused.
So if any one can tell me whats the latest way for this.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#struts), it has a dedicated chapter on Spring <=> Struts 1 & 2 integration

Comment: I actually found complete explanation on this page http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3.1/docs/spring-plugin.html

Comment: Also, i had struts2-spring-plugin.jar on my class path and looking inside this jar i found struts-plugin.xml which set spring as the default object factory for struts 2.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to clarify if you're using Struts 1 or Struts 2--the answers are very different on the Struts side.

On the Struts 2 side, there's a Spring plugin which essentially delegates all Struts 2 object creation to Spring, so you get all of the Spring wiring and so on without having to change any of your application's code or config.

In Struts 1, you'd generally declare your actions to be of the org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy class in your Struts 1 config file. In the Spring config you define a bean whose name matches the path, and is a Struts 1 Action subclass.

Struts 2's config file is "struts.xml" by default, but is configurable. Struts 1's config file is (again by default) "struts-config.xml". Either can have multiple config files.